# get_currentuserinfo is deprecated since version 4.5! Use wp_get_current_user() instead

Tags: wordpress-4.5

https://build.trac.wordpress.org/changeset/36278/trunk/wp-includes/pluggable-deprecated.php

After Install or update wordpress with 4.5.
Generate error:

> **Notice** : get_currentuserinfo is
>   **[deprecated function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Version_4.5#Deprecated_2)** since version 4.5! Use
>   wp_get_current_user() instead. in  **wp-includes\functions.php** on line 3662

[More info for issue & solution](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/possible-plugin-conflict-5?replies=6)

Comment: Why minus point? this one correct issue see on more info.

Comment: Note that it's generating a Notice, not an Error. This is significant, because it seems to indicate that your server is reporting PHP Notices. This may be because your wp-config.php has the "DEBUG" constant set to "true". If this is a production (ie: "live") web server, you should make sure that's turned off. On the other hand, if you're seeing this in a development server, then good for you - and resolve the issue as stated in the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just find in plugin or theme with text "**get_currentuserinfo**" and replace with **wp_get_current_user()**.

Because of [deprecated function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Version_4.5#Deprecated_2) get_currentuserinfo and arrived new function [_wp_get_current_user()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/_wp_get_current_user/) Since: WordPress 4.5.0

```
function get_currentuserinfo() { 
   _deprecated_function( __FUNCTION__, '4.5', 'wp_get_current_user()' ); 
   return wp_get_current_user(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below step. I recovered one of my blog from the same error.
1. Install **query monitor plugin**
2. Check out the admin bar notice and click on the highlighted warning.
3. The screen jumps to the detailed warning explanation.
4. The section Call Stack will tell you the exact location where get_currentuserinfo() is used.
5. To fix this issue just replace get_currentuserinfo() with wp_get_current_user()